# Unable to interpret CDF function numerically in order to calculate various probabilities

Tags: probability, statistics

I am having a difficult time trying to interpret the following CDF function ($Y$ is a discrete random variable.):

$$F(y) =\begin{cases} 0 &\mbox{for}& y < 1;\\
         0.3 &\mbox{for}&1 \leq y < 3;\\
         0.8 &\mbox{for}& 3\leq y < 6;\\
         1 &\mbox{for}& y \geq 6 \end{cases}$$

In order to solve for probabilities such as $P(Y=3)$, $P(Y<3)$, and $P(Y>1)$. I understand the concept of CDF's, and how their values are indicative of $P(Y\leq y)$, but I am not sure how to extract information like $P(Y=3)$, where the CDF only describes values of $Y$ being less than or greater than $3$.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, $P(Y=3)=P(Y\leq 3)-P(Y<3)$. Furthermore $$P(Y<3)=\lim_{y \to 3^-} F(y)$$ So $P(Y \leq 3) = F(3)=.8$ and $P(Y<3)=.3$ So $P(Y=3)= .5$

Comment: I do understand how that makes since, however I am stuck figuring out P(Y<3) at all, being that to me it seems I only know the probability for when Y is between 1 (inclusive) and 3 (which is 0.3).

Comment: I edited the answer to explain more hopefully

Comment: I appreciate you clarifying, thank you.

Comment: @Connor Burleson, make sure to click on the green check mark to accept the answer.